# Using Orchard CMS, where is favicon set?

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I've searched and found many places that talk about the favicon (within [OrchardCMS](https://orchardproject.net/)) and how to use a plugin that allows you to change it, but I would like to know which file specifically sets the web site favicon so I can alter that file.

**What I've Tried**

- I've searched stackoverflow.
- I've done a general web search.
- I've searched the official [Orchard CMS Docs](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/)

What is the name of the file in the content system and where is it located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled all of the source locally and did a search for the string "ico" in all CSHTML files.

I finally found the source:

It is found under the root folder of your Orchard CMS installation at:

```
Core/Shapes/Views/
```

in a file named

```
Documents.cshtml
```

In that file, you will find code which looks like the following:

```
@using Orchard.Localization
@using Orchard.Mvc.Html;
@using Orchard.UI.Resources;
@{
    RegisterLink(new LinkEntry {Type = "image/x-icon", Rel = "shortcut icon", 

Href = Url.Content("~/modules/orchard.themes/Content/Orchard.ico")});
    Script.Require("Html5Shiv").UseCondition("lt IE 9").AtHead();
```

The actual icon is found at the path (from root installation) :

```
/modules/orchard.themes/Content/
```

You can now simply alter that name (change Orchard.ico to whatever you want) and use your own icon.

Comment: You can create your own Document.cshtml file in your theme (copying the existing one).. Then, you may set your favicon at the location you want.